# YAML: AttributeError: ON for a key named "ON" in yaml file

Tags: python, yaml, robotframework

I have a YAML file which I am reading using Python/Robot Framework. But I am getting error for one of the key which is "ON".

```
SectionPage:
  AB: Sample Value AB
  ON: Sample Value ON
```

This `ON` key is also shown in red as compared to others which are blue.

[image]

Is there any specific reason why this is happening only for key=ON

[image]

Comment: Can you share a snippet where you are processing the YAML file?

Comment: "ON" is a reserved keyword in YAML used to represent a null value. Can you try using a different key?

Comment: @Kabilesh Thank you for pointing that out. I will use a different key name for that now.

Comment: @KayvanShah I am directly calling the key using ${SectionPage.ON} in robot script and all the processing is happening automatically. Kabilesh already pointed out what is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your highlighter uses a vastly outdated parser. In YAML 1.1 `ON` (and `On`/`Yes`/`YES`) were alternatives for the scalar `True`/`TRUE`/`true`. But that has been replaced by YAML 1.2 in 2009 and that specification no longer mentions these alternatives.

So unless you use the outdated PyYAML (which only supports a subset of YAML 1.1) to process the files, you can use `ON` as a key. If you are not sure, just make the document explicit YAML 1.2 with a directive:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
SectionPage:
  AB: Sample Value AB
  ON: Sample Value ON
```